# How can I binding big data from vuex with form?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying the Vue and I've got a problem with binding data from vuex with my form.
I created a simple store

```
export default {
  state: {
    form: {},
  },
  action: {
    async getForm({ commit }, id) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`url/${id}`);
        commit('setForm', response.data);
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setForm(state, payload) {
      state.form = payload;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getFormFromStore = state => state.form,
  },
}
```

And I ceated a simple component

```
data() {
  return {
    form: {},
  };
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('form', 'getFormFromStore'),
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions('form', 'getForm'),
},
watch: {
  getFormFromStore: {
    deep: true,
    handler(newVal) {
      this.form = Object.assign({}, newVal);
    },
  },
},
async mounted() {
  await this.getForm();
},
<div>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.name/>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.lastName/>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.age/>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.address.street/>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.address.house/>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.children.girl/>
    <v-text-field v-model=form.children.girl.name/>
  </v-form>
</div>
```

But I'm getting a problem when I try to change the form. And I don't know how to fix it.
I've read some articles, but it says that I need to create the computed properties, but if I have form with 100 fields?

My error

> Error [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

Comment: "But I'm getting a problem when I try to change the form" - what problem?

Comment: I've updated my question. @EstusFlask

Comment: You're setting a "mutations" object, are you connecting it to your [Vuex.Store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)?   Where and when are you calling setForm?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm calling setForm only into action after I get the data from API

Comment: OK, you might want to show us that part, as well as where you're attaching your mutations object to the store, since one of those is where the problem is likely occurring. (Are you maybe calling setForm directly, instead of using `store.commit()`?)

Comment: @DanielBeck const action = {
  async getForm({ commit }, id) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`url/${id}`);
      commit('setForm', response.data);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` makes a shallow copy of `state.form`. Two-way binding in `v-model` mutates the state.

The watcher should make a deep copy instead. If there are multiple levels of nesting, third-party utility for deep clone/merge can be used. A simple and less efficient way is to create a deep copy with `JSON` builtin:

```
  this.form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newVal));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to use cloneDeep from lodash ;)